# VBA Calculate Total Weekdays for Entire Row

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to calculate total of weekdays (Saturday and Sunday) from a range of time. The looping is OK but it do not give the result like I want. As an example, AD6 = 26/1/2015  5:00:00 PM AND T6 = 13/1/2015  8:05:00 AM should give 4 days but it give weird number 807878.

What does that's mean? How can I adjust my coding to get just like I want? There's the code I use for this process.
Thanks!

```
Sub CalcWeek()
Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, dateToCheck As Date
Dim daysBetween As Long, weekdays As Long, i As Long

Dim lrow As Long
Dim PRow As Long
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet
FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

weekdays = 0

For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1

For i = 0 To DateDiff("d", (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value), (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "T").Value))

dateToCheck = DateAdd("d", i, CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value)

If (Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 2 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 3 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 4 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 5 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 6) Then
CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AI").Value = CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AI").Value + 1
End If

Next i
'CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AJ").Value = weekdays
Next PRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly I got what I need!

```
Sub WeekDaysTotally()

Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, dateToCheck As Date
Dim daysBetween As Long, weekdays As Long, i As Long

Dim lrow As Long
Dim PRow As Long
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet
FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
weekdays = 0

Date1 = Cells(PRow, "T")
Date2 = Cells(PRow, "AD")
daysBetween = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)

For i = 0 To daysBetween

 dateToCheck = DateAdd("d", i, Date1)
 If Cells(PRow, "U").Value <> "" And Cells(PRow, "S").Value <> "" Then
 If (Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 2 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 3 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 4 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 5 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 6) Then
    weekdays = weekdays + 1
 End If
 End If
Next i

Cells(PRow, "AL") = weekdays

Next PRow
End Sub
```

This sub will calculate total number of weekdays only thorughout the cell. ><